# Can a TClientDataSet Nested (one-to-many) DataSets be created at runtime

Tags: delphi

Can TClientDataSet Nested (one-to-many) DataSets be created at runtime?
Is there any code that shows how to do this?

Thanks,

Bill

Answer (score 3):

[Nesting DataSets in ClientDataSets](http://dn.codegear.com/article/29825) by Cary Jensen should answer your question. Also look for other articles on this site by Cary for more information on ClientDataSets.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a one-to-many relationship isn't all that difficult.  It can be done at design-time or at runtime:

1. Create the master dataset.

   - Make sure it contains a primary key field.
   - Create the detail dataset.  Make sure it contains a foreign key field.
   - Link the detail dataset to the master dataset as follows:
   - Set the MasterSource property to the master dataset.
   - Set the MasterField property to the primary key field of the master dataset.
   - Set the IndexFieldNames property to the foreign key of the detail dataset.
   - Done!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? A client dataset is a single table. But you can create a field which contains another clientdataset (which must be extracted to be used).